# How do I achieve a successful base configuration of expo-facebook within an Expo managed app?

Tags: facebook, configuration, expo

**Platform/SDK Info**

- expo: 42.0.1
- expo-facebook: 12.0.3
- Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): all (including web only because we use Expo Go for development)
- Expo App Type: Managed

**Issue Description**

I’m attempting to complete the base level setup of the expo-facebook package. I’m running into configuration issues despite extensive research and configuration updates. I’m lead to believe our configuration is incorrect given what we’re seeing in https://business.facebook.com/. When going to that dashboard for our mobile app, there’s a lack of any baseline data. Additionally, if we continue navigating to the task center within that dashboard, we see the following critical tasks:

1. Update your apps to the latest Facebook SDK
2. Set up Apple’s SKAdNetwork API for your apps

**Our Configuration**

We are running an Expo Managed app. We’ve installed the versions of expo and expo-facebook listed at the top of this description. I’ve followed all the steps listed here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#configuration. In addition, we have the following configuration in our app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
      <unrelated configuration items>
    },
    "facebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled": true,
    "facebookAppId": "<our 15 digit facebook app id>",
    "facebookAutoInitEnabled": true,
    "facebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled": true,
    "facebookDisplayName": "<our three word display name including spaces>",
    "facebookScheme": "fb<our 15 digit facebook app id>"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.